# marionette render view is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have wrote a simple application that have two views, the first view load google search engine ui.

I have two routes, search route and home route, and I load the search route for the first time, it works well, but when I change route and to home and back to the search route, the search view will not work.

SearchView code:

```
var SearchView = Marionette.View.extend({
  template: "#search-template",
  onRender: function() {
    var cx = '010767762450613121260:fzszywg7ozm';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;

    var s = this.$el.find("#googleResult")[0];
    s.prepend(gcse);
  },
  events: {
    'click button': 'doSearch'
  },
  doSearch: function(e) {

    var input = document.getElementById('search-box-id');
                    var element = google.search.cse.element.getElement('searchresults-only0');
                    if (input.value == '') {
                        element.clearAllResults();
                    } else {
                        element.execute(input.value);
                    }
    log("Search for ");
  }
});
```

this is the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/kk266551/29/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I console I get such error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of null
    at n.doSearch ((index):127)`

This it that line: `element.execute(input.value);`

It means that it doesn't find element `searchresults-only0` on next render.

On next render element's name should be `searchresults-only1` and so on.

I tired to fix that by giving gname https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#gname and searching element by it but it didn't work either.

At last I found that the problem is that on each render Google script is reloaded and conflicts with itself.

So that's what I did in your script that made it work as expected:

```html
<gcse:searchresults-only gname="other"></gcse:searchresults-only>
```

```js
  onRender: function() {
     // check if Google script was loaded at least once
    if(!window.google) {
      var cx = '010767762450613121260:fzszywg7ozm';
      // saving gcse to global object
      var gcse = window.gcse = document.createElement('script');
      gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
      gcse.async = true;
      gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    } 
    var s = this.$el.find(".googleResult").last();
    s.prepend(window.gcse);
  },
```

```js
  doSearch: function(e) {
  
   var input = document.getElementById('search-box-id');
    var element = google.search.cse.element.getElement('other');
    if (input.value == '') {
      element.clearAllResults();
    } else {
      element.execute(input.value);
    }
   log("Search for ");
  }
```

You owe few bucks for some homeless man in a street.

Comment: We always awe few bucks to the poor and homeless, thank you very much @rytis